# Dupliverts Rotation

Tags: modeling, instances

I'll try to explain as simple as possible. I have made some dupliverts as seen in the images. On IMG 01, I add the wireframe, at **thickness 0.02** you can see on each vertex it has multiple mini icoshperes, so I lower the thickness to 0.01 and everything lowers with it (wireframe and mini icospheres become just one icosphere.

So then on IMG 02 I said, Ill just click on the **dispaly instancer** and add another Icosphere and add a wireframe modifier, which does the trick. but, I'm trying to parent the wireframe and Icosphere to be able to rotate them like one object, and while the wireframe is rotating, so is each icosphere on the wireframe individually. So I try to select all the object to parent them and I get a ultra complex mesh.

So Im trying to have the object as seen, Wireframe and Icosphere as one object. and to able to rotate.

[image]